# omxplayer (raspian) playing video folder on shuffled loop

Tags: linux, random, shuffle, omxplayer

I cannot find a way to use omxplayer in a shell script to play videos in a folder in a random "shuffle" order. I would like it to loop through a "playlist" but so far I have only been able to find a way to play all folders in alphabetical order in a loop. I use a version of the code below for the loop.

```
#!/bin/sh

# get rid of the curso so we don't see it when videos are running
setterm -cursor off

# set here the path to the directory containing your videos
VIDEOPATH="/home/pi/Videos"

# you can normally leave this alone
SERVICE="omxplayer"

# now for our infinite loop!
while true; do
    if ps ax | grep -v grep | grep $SERVICE > /dev/null
    then
    sleep 1;
else
    for entry in $VIDEOPATH/*
    do
        clear
        omxplayer $entry > /dev/null
    done
fi
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up combining the videos in Wondershare in various orders. This is not friendly to storage, because I essentially have several copies of the videos, but I can pick one of several orders to start playing and set it to loop which accomplishes most of my goal.

Loop code (much simpler than above code):
    `omxplayer -o local --loop /home/pi/video.mp4`